# Drawing a rectangle over an existing Graphics page

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java application which draws a drawing. I want to give the user the possibility to mark an area with the mouse (in order to, for example, zoom into it).
For that I use the MouseMotionListener class, and when the mouse is (clicked and then) moved, I save the location of the currently selected (it isn't final since the user haven't released the mouse) rectangle, and use the `repaint()` function. I wish to display that rectangle over the original drawing, making it similar to the Selection tool in MSPaint.

The problem is that when I call the `repaint()` function, the method `paintComponent (Graphics page)` is invoked, in which I use the method `super.paintComponent(page)` which erases my drawing. However, if I don't use that method when I know the user is selecting a rectangle, I get that all the selected rectangles are "packed" one above the other, and this is an undesirable result - I wish to display the currently selected rectangle only.

I thought I should be able to save a copy of the Graphics page of the drawing and somehow restore it every time the user moves the mouse, but I could not find any documentation for helpful methods.

Thank you very much,

Ron.

Edit: Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel
{
public FractalPanel()
   {
      addMouseListener (new MyListener());
      addMouseMotionListener (new MyListener());

      setBackground (Color.black);
      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200,200));
      setFocusable(true);
   }

public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
   {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        //that's where the drawing takes place: page.setColor(Color.red), page.drawOval(..) etc
   }
   private class MyListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
   {
   ...
      public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event) 
      {
          //saving the location of the rectangle
          isHoldingRectangle = true;
          repaint();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm betting that you are getting your Graphics object via a `getGraphics()` call on a component, and are disatisfied since this obtains a Graphics object which does not persist. It is for this reason that you shouldn't do this but instead just do your drawing inside of the JPanel's paintComponent. If you do this all will be happy.

As an aside -- we'll be able to help you better if you tell us more of the pertinent details of your problem such as how you're getting your Graphics object and how you're trying to draw with it, key issues here. Otherwise we're limited to taking wild guesses about what you're trying to do.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MandelDraw extends JPanel {
private static final String IMAGE_ADDR = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/" +
        "wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Mandel_zoom_07_satellite.jpg/" +
        "800px-Mandel_zoom_07_satellite.jpg";
private static final Color DRAWING_RECT_COLOR = new Color(200, 200, 255);
private static final Color DRAWN_RECT_COLOR = Color.blue;

   private BufferedImage image;
   private Rectangle rect = null;
   private boolean drawing = false;

   public MandelDraw() {
      try {
         image = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_ADDR));
         MyMouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
         addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
         addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (image != null) {
         return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
      }
      return super.getPreferredSize();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      if (image != null) {
         g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
      if (rect == null) {
         return;
      } else if (drawing) {
         g2.setColor(DRAWING_RECT_COLOR);
         g2.draw(rect);
      } else {
         g2.setColor(DRAWN_RECT_COLOR);
         g2.draw(rect);
      }
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      private Point mousePress = null; 
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         mousePress = e.getPoint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         drawing = true;
         int x = Math.min(mousePress.x, e.getPoint().x);
         int y = Math.min(mousePress.y, e.getPoint().y);
         int width = Math.abs(mousePress.x - e.getPoint().x);
         int height = Math.abs(mousePress.y - e.getPoint().y);

         rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         drawing = false;
         repaint();
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MandelDraw");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MandelDraw());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I'm no expert in the subject, so I'm just using a template which I got from a working example: I draw in the 'paintComponent (Graphics page)' method, using the very same Graphics object (page.drawLine etc.)

Comment: Sorry, again I'm reduced to guessing what you're doing since you've not shown us. If you're drawing your rectangle in paintComponent, then it shouldn't matter if you call repaint as paintComponent will simply re-draw it and all should be well. If our advice doesn't help, then *tell the details* and *show the code* so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't think you'd want to see the code. Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: We only need enough information so that we can see what your problem is. OK, the code you've posted should work, suggesting the problem may be elsewhere in code not shown. Does the DrawingPanel class have int or Rectangle variables to store the values obtained from the MouseListener/MouseMotionListener? Does the paintComponent method use these stored class fields to base its drawing on? What behaviors is  your code currently doing, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I forgot to say a very important thing - I don't wish to draw the background image each time the user moves the mouse, since it's very time consuming. So right now, if I write in paintComponent something along "if (isHoldingRectangle) page.drawRect(..)", it draws it well but redraws the whole image, ergo takes a lot of time. If I quite the method after the rectangle is drawn, I only see the rectangle, without the background image. I hope my problem is clearer now and I'm sorry again for not letting you know this earlier.

Comment: Why can't you draw it as it's being dragged? That shouldn't take up too much processing power since your Mandelbrot image will be displayed in a BufferedImage most likely. Please see edit to see what I mean.

Comment: I suppose the problem lies in the fact that I'm drawing the image pixel for pixel and not using a BufferedImage, i.e. if I did what you offered I'd have to calculate the sequence again for every pixel on the screen every time the user moves the mouse...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by recalculating with mouse moves. If you draw to a BufferedImage, you can mouse over all you'd like without having to redraw anything. I think that your program would likely benefit greatly by doing this (drawing to a BufferedImage), and in fact it is what I've done in previous Mandelbrot programs that I've done and has worked very well.

Comment: I know understand what you mean - to draw into a BufferedImage and every time paint it. I am going to use that, I think. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to repaint on every mouse movement:

```
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        //Update the rectangle holder object with that point coordinates
        repaint();
    }
```

You'll probably have a holder rectangle object to hold the initial and final rectangle points. The initials are set on mouse click, the final are modified on mouse dragged and on mouse released.

In `paint` method, clear the graphics and draw a rectangle with the coordinates in the holder. This is the basic idea.

UPDATE: How to draw a new shape on top of the existing image:
I'm thinking of two options:

1. If you are only drawing shapes (such as lines, rectangles and other Java2D stuff) you could have a Collection holding these shapes coordinates, and draw all of them on each `paint`. Pros: good when there are few shapes, allows undoing. Cons: When the number of shapes increase, the `paint` method will take more and more time in each pass.
2. Have a "background image". On each `paint` call, draw first the image and then the currently active shape on top. when an active shape is made persistent (onMouseReleased), it is saved to the background image. Pros: efficient, constant time. Cons: drawing a big background image on every mouse movement could be "expensive".

Comment: The problem is not with knowing what the rectangle is, the problem is with drawing it (and only it) over the original drawing.

Comment: That should be `paintComponent`, not `paint` since this is a Swing application, but your idea is correct -- 1+

Comment: What I mean is that on the `paint` (or `paintComponent`) method, you should only care of drawing a single rectangle. That's why you should hold some variables on your class (for instance, a `Reactangle`, or a couple of `Point`, or one of your own) that you'll update via the mouse listener and use on the `paint` to draw the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since the drawing is made pixel to pixel, I think I'll go with the second method - how to do that?

Comment: You have examples here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Comment: However, the best would be to redraw the big background image only when it changes, and repaint only the active shape on each mouse movement. I don't know how it could be done since every repaint clears the graphics.